# Divide list in two columns

Tags: php

I have list of values that I want to fetch from my database. So List is long I want to fetch list in two columns. How can I break it in 2 columns. Eg..

taking list of aphabets

```
A      |       B
C      |       D
E      |       F
G      |       H
I      |       J
K      |       L
```

IN this way. I used following approach...

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poet WHERE status='Publish' ORDER BY name ") or die(mysql_error());
    $total_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);


    $i = 1;
    $j = ceil($total_rows/2);

    while ( $i <= $j ) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
?> 

<tr>    
    <? if($i%2 == 0) { ?>   
        <td class="navigation"><?php echo fetch_table_poet( $result["pid"], 1, 3); ?></td>
    <? } elseif($i%2 != 0) { ?>  
        <td class="navigation"><?php echo fetch_table_poet( $result["pid"], 1, 3); ?></td>
    <? } ?>
</tr>

<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Its giving me output in this way..

```
A    |    A
B    |    B
C    |    C
```

**NOTE** -  I wish to do it using PHP not using any jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are resetting your result every time you loop. Set the $results outside the while. The more accepted way to do this is:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){


}
```

Then test $i to see if it is divisible by 2 (meaning you have 2 columns and need to add the end of row and beginning of new row tags).

```
if($i%2 == 0){
    echo '</tr><tr>';
}
```

Comment: If I wish to use it column wise instead of row-wise. I mean First 5 in first column and next five in second column?

Comment: Then only add the </tr><tr> is your $i == 5, then reset $i = 0, and do it again.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poet WHERE status='Publish' ORDER BY name ") or die(mysql_error());

$i = 0;
$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    while ( $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ) {
        $i++;
?> 


    <? if($i&1 == 1) { ?> 
 <tr>
        <td class="navigation"><?php echo $result["pid"]; ?></td>
    <? } elseif($i&1 == 0) { ?>  
        <td class="navigation"><?php echo $result["pid"]; ?></td>
</tr>
    <? } 
if($i == $total_rows && $total_rows&1 == 1){ echo "</tr>"; } ?>


<?php  } ?>
```

Edited: Bug fixes..

i think Colmn rows this will work:

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poet WHERE status='Publish' ORDER BY name ") or die(mysql_error());
    $total_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    $iOne = 1;
    $iTwo = floor($totalRows/2);

    foreach($iOne=1,$iTwo=ceil($totalRows/2); $iTwo < $total_rows; $iOne++,$iTwo++){
        ?>
        <tr>    
            <td class="navigation"><?php echo mysql_result($sql,$iOne,'pid') ?></td>
            <td class="navigation"><?php echo mysql_result($sql,$iTwo,'pid') ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php       
    }
?>
```

Comment: If I wish to use it column wise instead of row-wise. I mean First 5 in first column and next five in second column?

Comment: Than you could use Mysql_result($string, number of req, name of row) to get the even and odd numbers and displays them.. in a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest jQuery columnizer as a solution to your problem http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I succeeded with code.

```
    <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poet WHERE status='Publish' ORDER BY name ") or die(mysql_error());
    $total_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    $i = 1;
    while ( $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ) {   ?> 

        <?php if($i%2 == '1') { ?>
            <tr>    
                    <td class="navigation"><?php echo fetch_table_poet( $result["pid"], 1, 3); ?></td>
        <?php } elseif($i%2 == '0') { ?>
                    <td class="navigation"><?php echo fetch_table_poet( $result["pid"], 1, 3); ?></td>
            </tr>                       
        <?php } ?>

    <?php  $i++; } ?>
```